# Differential mapping not uniquely determined by f(x), when A is not an open set

Tags: real-analysis

This question I found in Elementary Classical Analysis Exercise 6.1.3

> Let $ A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x \in [0,1], y =0 \}$. Suppose $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ is differentiable at $x_0$. Prove $Df(x_0)$ is not uniquely determined by $f$.

I was able to get $T_1(x) = T_2(x), \forall x \in A$. However I feel this is not enough for me to state that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | T_1(x) \neq T_2(x)$. How can I make my argument more convincing, because intuitively I know that this has to be not equal since we can only approach $x_0$ on the interval given. My alternative way is to give an example of two linear transformations that would be legit only within $A$, but honestly I don't know how to construct the example using the right language.

Thanks!

Comment: What are $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Comment: What is the defiinition of $Df(x_0)$ in this case? I can make an "educated guess", but you should supply all relevant information.